# Is it bad practice to use the import * method with tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tk-toolkit

From what I've read and the reasons given, I know that the `from foo import *` method is bad practice, due to complications with variable assignment as well as memory problems. However, would the `tkinter` module be an exception to this rule?

I figure that when using a GUI, one may be looking to use perhaps most of the functions/methods from the respective module, where in comparison to something like `itertools`, one may only need access to a handful of modules (one wouldn't need to use `permutations` *and* `combinations`).

Independent of whether `tkinter` is an exception, are there any modules that are?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python has a [style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports), which is explicit about the one acceptable use for wildcard imports:

> Wildcard imports (`from <module> import *`) should be avoided, as they make it unclear which names are present in the namespace, confusing both readers and many automated tools. There is one defensible use case for a wildcard import, which is to republish an internal interface as part of a public API (for example, overwriting a pure Python implementation of an interface with the definitions from an optional accelerator module and exactly which definitions will be overwritten isn't known in advance).

Comment: Thanks for directing me to the style guide, never even knew this existed ^_^

Answer (score 5):

There are numerous problems with `from foo import *`; it can import lots of stuff that you didn't expect to, and especially something that overwrite the names of built-in functions or something that you imported from other modules. Worse yet, your program might work now, but when in a later version the author of `foo` module adds function `bar` in the module, your code could suddenly break if it expected `bar` to be something else.

The preferred way with long modules is often to import the module with a short alias:

```
import tkinter as tk
```

and then use for example `tk.Button`. This is the idiom used by the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/tkinter.html).

Comment: Ah, I never knew you could import foo as bar, or rather foobar as fb, that makes it really easy, thanks :)